# Complex SQL query on many to many

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have three tables in PostgreSQL:

```
1. product: id, name
2. param: id, name
3. param_product: id, product_id, param_id, value - (!) it's Many to Many
```

It's a problem with select product with, for example, "(param_id=1 and value=2000) and (param_id=2 and value=1000)"

What's the way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly the problem... you didn't mention it :)

Comment: Well, I need get unique product id's with parameters

Answer (score 1):

The approach to solving this also depends on what columns you want to return in your select. If all you want is the columns from product then it is simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_id = product.id AND param_id=1 and value=2000)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_id = product.id AND param_id=2 and value=1000)
```

Also, as far as SQL is concerned this is still a 1-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I could be getting the wrong end of the stick, but don't you just need something like

```
    SELECT pr.*
      FROM product pr
INNER JOIN param_product pp ON pr.id = pp.product_id
       AND pa.id = pp.param_id
     WHERE 
           (
           pa.id = 1
           AND pp.value = 2000
           )
        OR
           (
           pa.id = 2
           AND pp.value = 1000
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> (param_id=1 and value=2000) and (param_id=2 and value=1000)

Notice param_id can't be 1 AND 2 at the same time :) Try this instead:

`(param_id=1 and value=2000) OR (param_id=2 and value=1000)`

This will give you both param_id 1 where value equals 2000 and param_id 2 where value equals 1000.

Comment: yes, it's ok. But i need to get unique product_id where the first and the second parameters are 2000 and 1000.

Comment: Please, provide your current SELECT statement and update the question with it so that we can understand what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are designed for N:M relationships, of course you're going to have trouble selecting unique values. The easiest approach here would be using MIN() or MAX() functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(product.id)
FROM product
JOIN param_product ON param_product.product_id = product.id
WHERE param_id IN ('1000', '2000')
```

I think this should help you get on your way.

Also if product is unique to param, you dont need "id" column in your "param_product" table, you can assign primary key ON (product_id, param_id) columns since they are probably bound to be unique.

Comment: good note about the uniqueness constraint, which should be there even if someone is insisting on the synthetic primary key.